# Switch layers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I followed [this Mapbox GL JS example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) step by step to make our map layers show and hide.

However, in this case, if our visitors forget to close the layers on top, like with "April" on, when they click on "June", the layers of June cannot be seen, cause they are under April layers.

Is there any ways I can switch between layers? Or if I have one button on the others will be turned off automatically?

My code is below.

HTML:

```
<div id='map'></div>
<nav id="menu"></nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyY3VzcGciLCJhIjoiY2l2NmdtZjdyMDAwMjJ6bDVhb2JndDlrMiJ9.EopxTk2v-1WrWsgbLmL_XA';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map', // container id
  style: 'mapbox://styles/marcuspg/cj6xc2cb49xpg2sqpuuwbob0u', // stylesheet location
  //center:[]
  //zoom:13
});

// add a map layer_3d buildings
map.on('load', function() {
  map.addLayer({
    'id': '3d-buildings',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'building',
    'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
    'minzoom': 15,
    'paint': {
      'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',
      'fill-extrusion-height': {
        'type': 'identity',
        'property': 'height'
      },
      'fill-extrusion-base': {
        'type': 'identity',
        'property': 'min_height'
      },
      'fill-extrusion-opacity': .6
    }
  });
});

// group two layers into one
toggleLayer(['April','April_2'], 'April');
toggleLayer(['June','June_2'], 'June');
toggleLayer(['September', 'September_2'], 'September');
toggleLayer(['December','December_2'], 'December');


function toggleLayer(ids, name) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '#';
    link.className = 'active';
    link.textContent = name;

    link.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        for (layers in ids){
            var visibility = map.getLayoutProperty(ids[layers], 'visibility');
            if (visibility === 'visible') {
                map.setLayoutProperty(ids[layers], 'visibility', 'none');
                this.className = '';
            } else {
                this.className = 'active';
                map.setLayoutProperty(ids[layers], 'visibility', 'visible');
            }
         }


    };

    var layers = document.getElementById('menu');
    layers.appendChild(link);
}
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menu a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #404040;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  text-align: center;
}

#menu a:last-child {
  border: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #404040;
}

#menu a.active {
  background-color: #3887be;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#menu a.active:hover {
  background: #3074a4;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tianyiy/Ljujba4b/7/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Do not *link* to your source code. Add it as well formatted code to the question. Links break, and then your question renders useless for future readers.